# Is this sample size big enough to analyze with Propensity Score Matching?

Tags: regression, logistic, propensity-scores, matching

Suppose I have a dataset where 9 patients occured with the post-operative complication.
(e.g. information such as height, smoking, weight, age, disease status) and rest of the 150 patients without the post-operative complication.

In this case, I only can have 9 as the number of control group and experimental group respectively at most.

Just in general, the statistical analysis result with this dataset can be valid or not?

Comment: there is no universal threshold which will give you a definite answer to that. The only thing we can say for sure is that the larger the sample the better the statistical power.

Comment: @utobi Thanks for a comment. That's really true. I just like to know how big it should, and the decent sample size  just in general to write a medical paper to persuade with statistical analysis.

Comment: I would say that sample size is not enough to even analyze a randomized trial, let alone an observational study with propensity score analysis. Would you trust the results of a study with only 9 participants in one of the treatment groups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at both aspects of your question separately: PS matching and sample size calculations.

### Propensity score matching

When you do propensity score matching, you are aiming to balance your groups on a set of observed covariates that inform treatment. By matching people who have (largely) similar propensity scores, we can try to achieve this balance between groups. However, you are **not** limited to matching on a 1:1 ratio. You could for example match the groups 1:10, meaning you could get 9 individuals in the exposure group and 90 in the unexposed group. Mind you that at a certain point matching more individuals becomes statistically redundant though, as you are still limited by the 9 people in the exposed group.

One alternative to PS matching could be PS weighting, where you weight individuals up or down based on their propensity score, but do not remove any individuals from the dataset. This can still allow you to balance the groups on covariates. A great paper introducing this concept and helping you choose the PS weight is [Desai & Franklin 2019 BMJ](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31645336/).

### Sample size calculations

To determine whether our random sample from the (theoretical supra)population is large enough in regards to random sample variation, there exist formal sample size formulas. A great introduction to sample size calculations is [Noordzij *et al.* 2010 Nephrol Dial Transplant](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/20067907/).

With 9 individuals in one group, from experience I would say that your sample size is likely too small to detect any meaningful differences, but with the sample size calculations, you can still detect how many individuals you would need to be able to detect a meaningful difference, so I strongly suggest you try these out.

Mind you that for different objectives in medical research, different sample size calculations exist: they differ for different outcomes, different modelling strategies, and different objects (e.g., detecting a difference vs. creating a prediction model).

#### Sources

In case the links didn't work, here are the citations of the works I mentioned. Both are open-access.

- Desai RJ, Franklin JM. Alternative approaches for confounding adjustment in observational studies using weighting based on the propensity score: a primer for practitioners. BMJ. 2019 Oct 23;367:l5657. doi: 10.1136/bmj.l5657.
- Noordzij M, Tripepi G, Dekker FW, Zoccali C, Tanck MW, Jager KJ. Sample size calculations: basic principles and common pitfalls. Nephrol Dial Transplant. 2010 May;25(5):1388-93. doi: 10.1093/ndt/gfp732. Epub 2010 Jan 12. Erratum in: Nephrol Dial Transplant. 2010 Oct;25(10):3461-2. PMID: 20067907.

Comment: Thanks for the very understandable answer. I have one thing to worry about when implementing 1:10 ratio for propensity score matching. Should the rest of 9 patients come within caliper width 0.2 that I choose? Do I need to change it to something like 1.0 in order to have 10 pairs for each?

Comment: @nan you should try and base the caliper width based on what width is acceptable to balance groups. If a caliper width of 0.2 does not allow you to match 10 individuals each to one person in the exposed group, this might be another indication that your sample size is (too) small. Seemingly then, there is much variation in the PS in your sample, leading to few PSs that are within that caliper width. See also [this paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/20925139/).

Comment: Thanks for the extra information. I've read the paper above and found out and caliper width should be set as 0.2 as long as some covariates such as Age and BMI are continuous. So I'll choose the less pairs over the more pairs with wider caliper width.